# Concat a predefined string and variable in Go templates

Tags: go

I am trying to build a link in my Go template. I want my objects ID to be concatenated with a word to form a dynamic url.

When I print `{{.ID}}` on the page, I can see the correct ID printed, I am attempting to build the URL using Printf like so.

```
{{- $id := printf "/%s/%s" "wallet/" .ID -}}
        <a href={{$id}}><h1>Wallet ID {{.ID}}</h1></a>
```

In my browser it comes out as

> http://localhost:8000/wallet//%25!s%28int=1006608996216725456%29

Rather than what it should look like below. ID is of type int.

> http://localhost:8000/wallet/1006608996216725456

Comment: `printf "/%s/%d" "wallet" .ID`

Comment: `<a href="/wallet/{{.ID}}">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (escaped) `%!s...` indicates that the argument passed to `printf` is not a string. It even tells you the data type.

For example, if I run the following:

```
fmt.Printf("%s", int64(1006608996216725456))
```

I get:

```
%!s(int64=1006608996216725456)
```

You should either use `%d` in your `printf` or pass a string `ID`.